# Angular 2 @angular/router 3.0.0-alpha.7 - Accessing Multiple Parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am just trying the new router in Angular 2 announced recently i.e. Angular 2 @angular/router 3.0.0-alpha.7

I know that in new router we can access route parameters using below code:

```
this.activatedRoute.params
            .map(params => params['id'])
            .subscribe((id) => {

             //use param id

             });
```

Can anyone please guide how do we handle the case in which we have multiple multiple parameters in our route?

I mean how do we retrieve the values of multiple parameters from route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do it is using [Parameter handling](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_parameter-handling.html) and [Destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html) like this:

```
this.activatedRoute.params
  .map(params => [params['id'], params['p2'], params['p3']]) <== pass desired array
  .subscribe(([id, p2, p3]) => { <== destructuring params
      //use param id, p2 or p3
   });
```

See also HeroDetailComponent component here http://plnkr.co/edit/JtuOAZsZPhkn1CISQaO9?p=preview

Or you can write a bit simple:

```
this.activatedRoute.params
  .subscribe(({id, p2, p3}) => { <== destructuring params
      //use param id, p2 or p3
   });
```

[**Plunker sample**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3AAwxHUQ6JFdOFHg0OMq?p=preview) (HeroDetailComponent)

Comment: Thank you so much Yurzui, can you please also guide which approach would be better in case of a single parameter  .map(params => params['id']) or the one you suggested above.

Comment: I think there is no prefered approach. Destructuring is just syntax sugar. You can also have a look at approach from angular2 documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#get-route-parameter