# How can I target the top level router-outlet in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In Angular 2, I have a top level menu with among others products. When you click on products, you get a list of products in the top level router-outlet. When you then click on an individual product, you get details of that individual product, where you can click on versions and so on. So far, this targets nested router-outlets and everything works great. A working link looks like this:

http://localhost:4200/products/123/versions

However, when a user clicks the details of a specific version, I want to target a higher level router-link. So when you get the following link:

http://localhost:4200/products/123/versions/2

This is not loaded into a child router-outlet again, but I want to target the same router-outlet the product (ProductComponent) was shown in (which is the top level router-outlet). I know it is easy to do when I just have /versions/2, but I want to keep the context of the product in there. I also looked at naming the top-level outlet, but this does mean I have to change all of my routerlinks to include this name.

Is there another option I don't know about or a best practice I am missing? (couldn't find a good example in the Angular 2 docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ path: 'products/123/versions/:id', component: productsComponent }` can allow you to use a dynamic pathing.

Capture the id from the specific cmp using:

`this.paramsSub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => this.param = params['id']);`

```
routerLink = 'products/123/versions/'
routerLink = 'products/123/versions/2'
[routerLink] = ['products/123/versions/']
[routerLink] = ['products/123/versions/2']
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand, I have to add a router config entry at the same hierarchical level as the ProductComponent instead of as a child of ProductVersions which is a child of ProductComponent etc.

Comment: Right. Rather than creating a child - you can directly specify 'ROUTE/:id' on the ProductComponent's route definition and capture that using subscription to activatedRoute.params

Comment: Thanks again. I think found the answer that I needed for the multiple parameters here by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903073/angular-2-angular-router-3-0-0-alpha-7-accessing-multiple-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below code,

```
   <a [routerLink]="['/products/123/versions']" [queryParams]="{id:id}"></a>
```

And in your child route you can use like this

```
 { path: 'products/123/versions', component: productsComponent }
```